# Remixjs with passportjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, passport.js

Could anyone please post an example of Remixjs with passportjs. I checked remix-auth but didn't like it much.

I tried using remix-auth with [remix-auth-discord](https://github.com/JonnyBnator/remix-auth-discord) for discord authentication but it didn't meet up to my expectation as discord strategy doesn't exactly return the guilds joined by the user even if guild scope has been used.

```
//services/session.server.tsx
import { createCookieSessionStorage } from "@remix-run/node";

export let sessionStorage = createCookieSessionStorage({
  cookie: {
    name: "_session", 
    sameSite: "lax", 
    path: "/", 
    httpOnly: true, 
    secrets: ["SeCrEt69869"], 
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  },
});
```

```
//auth/server.ts
import { Authenticator } from "remix-auth";
import { DiscordStrategy } from "remix-auth-discord";
import { sessionStorage } from "~/services/session.server";
export const authenticator = new Authenticator(sessionStorage)
const discordStrategy = new DiscordStrategy(
    {
        clientID:process.env.clientId,
        clientSecret:process.env.clientSecret,
        callbackURL:process.env.callBackUrl,
        scope:["identify","email","guilds"]
    },
    async (acessToken) =>{
        const {profile} = acessToken
        const {id,emails,photos,__json} = profile
        const {username,email} = __json
        console.log({username,email,id,emails,photos})
    }
)
authenticator.use(discordStrategy)
```

```
//routes/auth.tsx
import { Form } from "@remix-run/react"
const auth = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <Form action="/auth/discord" method="post">
      <button>Login</button>
    </Form>
  </div>
  )
}

export default auth
```

```
//routes/dashboard.tsx
import type { LoaderFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
import { authenticator } from "~/auth/server";
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
 await authenticator
    .isAuthenticated(request, {
      failureRedirect: "/auth",
    })
  return json("Hello World");
};
export default function DashboardPage() {
  return <div>Dashboard</div>;
}
```

```
//route/auth/discord.tsx
import type { ActionFunction, LoaderFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
import { redirect } from "@remix-run/node";
import { authenticator } from "~/auth/server";
export const loader: LoaderFunction = () => {
  return redirect("/auth");
};
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
   await authenticator
    .authenticate("discord", request)
  return json("Hello World");
};
const discord = () => {
  return <div>discord</div>;
};

export default discord;
```

```
//route/auth/discord/callback.tsx
import type { LoaderFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
import { authenticator } from "~/auth/server";
export const loader: LoaderFunction = ({ request }) => {
   authenticator
    .authenticate("discord", request, {
      successRedirect: "/dashboard",
      failureRedirect: "/auth",
    })
    return json("Hello World");
};
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.